# Call a SQL stored procedure in ASP.NET with an output parameter

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm attempting to call my sql stored procedure which takes `RaceDate` as an input and returns `Location` as an OUTPUT. I'm not sure how to call my code in ASP.NET, this is what I have thus far.

```
DateTime RaceDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
    // string RaceDate = TxtBoxCalendar.Text;

    TxtBoxCalendar.ReadOnly = true;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ToString(); 

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand();

    Command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
    Command.CommandText = "CheckRaceCalendarDates";

    Command.Parameters.Add("@RaceDate", SqlDbType.DateTime, RaceDate);
    Command.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.String).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    Command.Parameters.Add("@Location",SqlDbType.String).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

I think i may also run into a problem with datatypes. `RaceDate` is a date the user clicks through a calendar and has to be converted to a string however the SQL parameter `RaceDate` is of type date.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckRaceCalendarDates]
@RaceDates DATE,
@Location NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
AS
IF EXISTS 
    (
SELECT 
    RaceCalendar.RaceDates,
    Locations.LocationName 
FROM 
    Locations
INNER JOIN RaceCalendar ON locations.LocationId = RaceCalendar.LocationId
WHERE 
    RaceCalendar.RaceDates = @RaceDates
    )

    BEGIN
SELECT 
    @Location = Locations.LocationName 
FROM 
    Locations
INNER JOIN RaceCalendar ON locations.LocationId = RaceCalendar.LocationId
WHERE 
    RaceCalendar.RaceDates = @RaceDates
    END
```

Comment: Use the Add method instead of AddWithValue and then specify the direction of the parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using stored procedure output parameters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905782/using-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: On a different note, if no rows are returned then `@Location` will have a value of `NULL`, which it would do if the query doesn't run. There's no need for the`IF` statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11293220/1507566

Comment: Why convert a date from a picker to a string, then back to a date for the SP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using stored procedure output parameters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905782/using-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-c-sharp)

Comment: So how would you get the date from the calendar? Something like:  DateTime RaceDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;?

Comment: I have a problem with my data types, see my changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem about using parameter name ; you have used `@RaceDates` on stored procedure but you try to use `@RaceDate` on code.. They should be same.

Also, you need to add second parameter to your code like this ;

```
Command.Parameters.Add("@Location",SqlDbType.String).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

And after `cmd.ExeCuteNonQuery();`

```
string location = Command.Parameters["@Location"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Getting an error with datatypes: "Cannot convert from system.datetime to int". DateTime RaceDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;

        Command.Parameters.Add("@RaceDates", SqlDbType.DateTime, RaceDate);

Comment: Where you use int type ? I could not see, use int anywhere your code, please check carefully