# Insert data into table and get ID from increased primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

In my ASP.NET application I have a need to do something like this: First, get data from a user, second insert this data into SQL Server database table, then get the `ID` value from that table (which is autoincremented) and then use it in another insert into another table.

Now, I already found out that in order to do this, I need to use T-SQL `OUTPUT` clause. However, when I try to do this I get this error:

[image]

I tried to follow the advice from those posts: 
[Get output parameter value in ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290652/get-output-parameter-value-in-ado-net) and [Use SQL Server Stored procedure output in asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292940/use-sql-server-stored-procedure-output-in-asp-net-c-sharp)
but I couldn't make it work.

I'm not using stored procedure, but the single SQL statement instead. Here it is:

```
INSERT INTO BS_product_sets (User_id, Set_name, Set_id, Products_count) 
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @NEWID 
VALUES (@UID, @SNAME, @SPREFIX, @PCOUNT)
```

I also tried this:

```
DECLARE @NEWID int; 

INSERT INTO BS_product_sets (User_id, Set_name, Set_id, Products_count) 
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @NEWID 
VALUES (@UID, @SNAME, @SPREFIX, @PCOUNT)
```

But then it gets even weirder because the error I get is:

[image]

Does anyone of you know how to resolve it? Here is the rest of my code in C#:

```
public void InsertProductAutoBinds(int user_id, int parameters_count, List<int> cat_ids, List<string> names, List<string> values, string set_name, string set_id)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConstants.ConnectionString);

    // Adding set to database
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(DatabaseConstants.InsertSet, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", user_id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SNAME", set_name);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SPREFIX", set_id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCOUNT", 0);
    command.Parameters.Add("@NEWID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    int new_inserted_id = Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["@NEWID"].Value);

    connection.Close();

    // Adding binds
    command = new SqlCommand(DatabaseConstants.InsertAutoBinds1, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", user_id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SID", new_inserted_id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1ID", cat_ids[0]);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VN1", names[0]);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VS1", values[0]);

    if (parameters_count > 1)
    {
        command.CommandText = DatabaseConstants.InsertAutoBinds2;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2ID", cat_ids[1]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VN2", names[1]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VS2", values[1]);
    }

    if (parameters_count > 2)
    {
        command.CommandText = DatabaseConstants.InsertAutoBinds3;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P3ID", cat_ids[2]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VN3", names[2]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VS3", values[2]);
    }

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [official MS documentation for `INSERT INTO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), you'd see:

*OUTPUT  INTO { @table_variable | output_table }*

That means: the `OUTPUT ... INTO ....` clause **only works** with a table or table variable as its target - you **cannot** do an `OUTPUT .... INTO @variable` - that's just plain not supported.

So you need to

- either do an `OUTPUT ... INTO @tableVar` and then select the first value from that table variable and return it
- just use `OUTPUT inserted.ID` (*without* any `INTO ....`) and just grab the value being returned from the SQL command in your C# code - in this case, since data **is** being returned, you need to use `.ExecuteScalar()` instead of `.ExecuteNonQuery()` in your C# code

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (Id Int IDENTITY, User_Id Int, ...)

DECLARE @NewID Int

INSERT INTO tab (User_Id,...) VALUES (123, ...)

SET @NewId = @@Identity
```